# Screwed up the lightdm.conf file, now what?

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm

I screwed up the lightdm.conf file as superuser.

What I was trying to do: I tried to insert a command (`xbacklight -set 50`) that sets my monitor brightness at the lightdm config file. Now when I start my laptop, it gets stuck at the xubuntu loading screen, so I can't login.

Is there a way to go into the shell/command-line and fix the lightdm.conf file??

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a different [virtual console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con/4132#4132). You will have a text mode login prompt.

Once you've done your repairs, you can switch back to the virtual console with the X window display by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

If you want to have several terminals, you get 6 virtual consoles with a login prompt by default: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into recovery mode, when the recovery menu is up, use the "Root Shell" option to gain a shell, then remove the command in the lightdm.conf.

Comment: CTRL ALT F1 did the trick. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Got what I needed on Google.

Solution: CTRL + ALT + F1 at the xubuntu loading screen. Then gained access to the shell, used vim to edit the file and then removed the commands I had inserted on it that was preventing lightdm from starting..